# Chart js [React js]

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, linechart

When we have more data coming in the response, then we have to show only 8 data points(timestamps) in the x axis.
We will show 8 data points(timestamps) based on the Total duration coming from the response.
Total duration is the time(minutes) from the start time to end time which is coming from the response.

For example: Total duration is 19h 0m 44s
19h 0m 44s in minutes is 1140 minutes.

Therefore 1140/8 = 142 is the interval between 8 data points(timestamps)

```
type here
```

Currently 10 data points(timetamps) are coming from the response.It should actually show 8 timestamps in x-axis in the graph.But is now showing only 5 data points.

[image]

[image]

The props which I provided are attached here:

```
x: {

        border: {

          color: "#655B96",

        },

        color: "red",

        offset: true,

        // borderColor: "red",

        grid: {

          drawOnChartArea: false,

          color: "#655B96",

        },

        title: {

          text: "Time",

          display: true,

        },

        ticks: {

          count: 8,

          autoSkip: true,

          maxTicksLimit: 8,

        },

      }
```